# JAR Unable to load text files after export

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, nullpointerexception, lwjgl

I've been working on a 3D game engine with Java, OpenGL/LWJGL and Slick-Utils and I can't get past this one bug (a Null Pointer Exception) in the program.

The Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at engineTester.Main.main(Main.java:22)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hybridia.engine3D.shaders.StaticShader.<clinit>(StaticShader.java:13)
            ... 1 more
```

Line 22 of engineTester.Main.main is where the StaticShader is initialized.

The file that the code descends from (line with the error has a comment next to it):

```
    package com.hybridia.engine3D.shaders;
    import java.net.URL;

    import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Matrix4f;

    public class StaticShader extends ShaderProgram {

    private int location_transformationLocaiton;

    private static final String VERTEX_FILE = URL.class.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource("/resc/shaders/vertexShader.txt").toString(); //Error Here
    private static final String FRAGMENT_FILE = URL.class.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource("/resc/shaders/fragmentShader.txt").toString();

    public StaticShader() {
        super(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindAttributes() {
        super.bindAttribute(0, "position");
        super.bindAttribute(1, "textureCoords");
    }

    @Override
    protected void getAllUniformLocations() {
        location_transformationLocaiton = super.getUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");

    }

    public void loadTransformation(Matrix4f matrix) {
        super.loadMatrix(location_transformationLocaiton, matrix);
    }

}
```

(There's also an error the next line (FRAGMENT_FILE) but fixing the first will fix the second.)

*What I'm trying to do:*

I export this project as a JAR to be usable for my future 3D projects. However, when I run it in my test project, I get the error above. I've tried several methods (shown below) but I either get a `Null Pointer exception` or `File Not Found exception`. The `StaticShader` class inherits from the `ShaderProgam` class which takes the `VERTEX_FILE` and `FRAGMENT_FILE` and uses the GLSL code to do its things with the VAOs and VBOs.

I know the problem is in line 13 (the line with the `//Error Here` comment). For some reason whatever I've tried to do fails. I know the files exist 100% because in the test project's Referenced Libraries I see the "vertexShader.txt" and "fragmentShader.txt." I have (quite literally) put the two files everywhere in the program hoping it would be able to be read by the StaticShader/ShaderProgram. I have created a folder for the two text files and the folder is apart of the build path.

I'd post an image of the hierarchy so it would look pretty and be easier to understand, but I don't have the reputation to do so. This is the best representation of the hierarchy without the picture:

```
SpaghettiEngineMKIII
|
|
|
|com.hybridia.engine3D.shaders
|        |ShaderProgram
|        |StaticShader
|
|
|resc
   |shaders
       |vertexShader.txt
       |fragmentShader.txt
```

*Methods I've tried to solve this:* (Just a little proof I tried fixing the bug on my own)

- InputStream
- InputStream and BufferedReader
- URL
- InputStream and URL
- Passing a String through the `super` without using URL/InputStream

*To Repeat/TL;DR:*

I have exported this project and made it a JAR file. I have added said JAR to the Build Path of a test project to test the render limits. However, the shader files are unable to be found/accessed when the test project is launched despite constant tinkering with the searching code in the StaticShader class. Could this be an issue of a path being wrong/not relative or absolute or is there a different way I have to grab the text files from what I've done?

Quick little history: The project worked fine when the StaticShader was in the test project and not the game engine project. I moved it because as I coded on, I needed to reference the StaticShader in other classes in the engine itself.

I'm sorry if anything comes off as "snappy," I do not intend for that to happen.

**EDIT:**

The ShaderProgram actually reads the files, the StaticShader finds the files and does all the fun stuff of creating the VBOs. I forgot to mention that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The NPE seems to come from the resource. It seems the class loader for URL is not the same as the one including your jar file.
Have you tried changing the error line to this?:

```
private static final String VERTEX_FILE = StaticShader.class.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource("/resc/shaders/vertexShader.txt").toString();
```

StaticShader.class is included in the same jar file as the txt file, so I would expect this to work...

Comment: It didn't work surprisingly. It returns an NPE; the same one as before in the same place. The `resc` folder is listed under the Library in Build Path. Should I make it a source folder instead of a library and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
 URL.class.getClass() ...
```

Your are asking the system for the *class* of the **URL.class** which returns the **java.lang.Class.class** class.  What is happening then is the class loader for the **java.lang.Class.class** is not able to find your resource relative to where the bytes for **java.lang.Class.class** is loaded.

Using the suggestions from h3f3st0, you want to use a class that is inside your jar file so change your call to

```
private static final String VERTEX_FILE = StaticShader.class.getClassLoader()
        .getResource("/resc/shaders/vertexShader.txt").toString();
```

and see if that doesn't help.

EDIT:

The option that works for me is as listed in the comments, use **getResourceAsStream()** instead of the **getResource()**.

Comment: Still returns an NPE. Could it be that I have to place the two txt files somewhere else/in the src folder or make the resc folder a source folder instead of a library folder?

Comment: If your hierarchy above is the layout of your jar, that seems to be fine, I know that when I package assets in a jar what I tend to use is more like  AssetManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/full/path/to/asset.gi") to get the InputStream then if that is not null, read the data in.

Comment: That method of using an InputStream worked! Thank you very much! I'm not sure how I should proceed... Should I write a response to my own question saying what I did or wait for you to update/make a new response seeing as I used your method of the InputStream?